# r optimization: Hold sum of two variables constant

Tags: r, optimization

I am running an optimization (simplified example below).  In the example, I am trying minimize the risk to a portfolio of assets (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j) during one economic environment (k1), for a given acceptable level of risk in during time periods characterized by another economic environment (k2).  I would like to be able to make sure that a+g=1 but I can't figure out how to make that constraint.  So far, I have only been able to make sure than c=d=0.  Also, my real world use for this has many more variables and many more rows in k1 and k2 so any ideas you guys have for making this faster are much appreciated.

```
library(nloptr)

#Build a data set
set.seed(4)
k1<-matrix(sample(-100:100, 1000, replace=T), ncol=10)
set.seed(6)
k2<-matrix(sample(-100:100, 1000, replace=T), ncol=10)
colnames(k1)<-letters[1:10]
colnames(k2)<-letters[1:10]

#Function to be minimized
fn<-function(H) {
    Y<-t(t(k1)*(H))
    return(quantile(rowSums(Y), .05, na.rm=TRUE)+400)
}

#For a given eqn
eqn<-function(H) {
    Y<-t(t(k2)*(H))
    return(quantile(rowSums(Y), .05, na.rm=TRUE))
}

#Lower and upper bounds (c=d=0)
lb<-rep(0, 10)
ub<-rep(1,10)
ub[3:4]<-0

#Guess solution
pars<-rep(1, 10)
pars[3:4]<-0

sol <- auglag(pars, fn=fn, gr=NULL, heq=eqn, lower=lb, upper=ub, nl.info = FALSE, control = list(xtol_rel = 1e-8, maxeval = 20000))
```

Comment: The NLopt info page says equality constraints in the form h(...)=0 are supported so this can be accomplished by asserting:  `a+b-1=0`. I'm not seeing any of `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d` in your code, so how your example relates to your problem definition is unclear to me.

Comment: @42- Sorry if I was not clear.  I set the column headers in k1 and k2 equal to letters[1:10].  I was assuming that, since pars is a ten element vector, each element corresponds to a column in k1 and k2.  So, if I wanted to set a+g=1, it would be the first and seventh element of pars.

Comment: You might have had better success at communication if you explained what you were attempting.  Setting the starting values of c and d equal to zero is not achieving what you think. Having two different  k-matrices confuses the problem as well.

Comment: @42- I want to hold the value of C and D at zero so I set the initial guess equal to zero and set their upper and lower bounds equal to zero.  When I look at sol, it looks like they are zero in the solution.

Comment: Ok that answers part 1, but why are there two different k matrices? And that is one heck of a weird goal function. You really ought to explain that. (Once that makes sense I have a solution for your equality constraints.)

Comment: @42- Each is calculating risk to the portfolio in a different way.  Basically, I have simulated prices during two different market environments.  I am willing to tolerate a certain amount of risk in a period similar to k2 but I want to minimize the risk as much as possible in environments like k1.

Comment: The k1 and k2 matrices would both need to be in the `fn`, and the parameters would need to be in the constraints.

Comment: @42- I think k2 needs to be in eqn because I am trying to minimize risk associated with k1 for a given level of risk associated with k2.  I am having trouble getting that constraint in there along with setting a+g=1.

Comment: Exactly. The k2 calculations are not an equality constraint, but rather part of the optimization goal or perhaps in the inequality conatraints. If you want to weight a few different quantiles of some risk measure, fine, but do it in the `fn`-goal or `hin`. The equality constraint _for_the_parameters_ is exact and easy to achieve.

Comment: If you edit your question to include the material you put in the comments, I'll be able to remove my downvote. You _are_ supposed to use the [edit] capacity to respond substantively (as you did) to comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution for the inequality constraint. The `k2` matrix has no business being in the equality function, since as I understand it from your comments you only wanted to avoid being in a "high-risk place" not necessarily be exactly at a particular level of "risk". That risk minimization concern either belongs in the `hin` (inequality specification) or in the goal function. This strategy removes the need to set the upper and lower bounds of the `'b'` and `'c'` parameters at the same value. (That is the reason for having an equality constraint.) Just set the abs() or sum of the squared values as the `return` from the function.

```
 eqn<-function(H) {
       (sum( H[ c(1,7) ]) -1)^2 +abs(H[2]) +abs(H[3])
    }
```

This shows successful completion and values of H[ c(1,2,3,7) that are consistent with your specification:

```
k1<-matrix(sample(-100:100, 1000, replace=T), ncol=10)
set.seed(6)
k2<-matrix(sample(-100:100, 1000, replace=T), ncol=10)
colnames(k1)<-letters[1:10]
colnames(k2)<-letters[1:10]
fn<-function(H) {
    Y<-t(t(k1)*(H))
    return(quantile(rowSums(Y), .05, na.rm=TRUE)+400)
}
eqn<-function(H) {
     (sum( H[c(1,7)]) -1)^2 +abs(H[2]) +abs(H[3])
}
lb<-rep(0, 10)
ub<-rep(1,10)
pars<-rep(1, 10)
pars[3:4]<-0
pars[c(1,7)] <- .5
sol <- auglag(pars, fn=fn, gr=NULL, heq=eqn, lower=lb, upper=ub, nl.info = FALSE, control = list(xtol_rel = 1e-8, maxeval = 20000))
#--------
> sol
$par
 [1] 6.678320e-01 1.445484e-20 5.193411e-21 2.230321e-01 9.168071e-01
 [6] 1.000000e+00 3.321727e-01 4.100418e-07 9.999992e-01 1.000000e+00

$value
[1] 122.3241

$iter
[1] 20001

$global_solver
[1] "NLOPT_LN_AUGLAG"

$local_solver
[1] "NLOPT_LN_COBYLA"

$convergence
[1] 5

$message
[1] "NLOPT_MAXEVAL_REACHED: Optimization stopped because maxeval (above) was reached."
```

Comment: this is interesting, I would not have thought of it.  I am a little confused as to where I can specify the level of k2 risk that I want to hold constant.

Comment: I have a hard time imagining you actually want a "constant" level of risk. I think you want to maximize return subject to avoiding more than a specified amount of loss. So the "risk" function should be in the inequality and the amount of risk would be the "floor" for that inequality. Now... will you PLEASE edit your question?

Comment: How does your eqn work?  Is the optimizer addressing each expression individually or setting the entire sum equal to zero?

Comment: It is requiring the entire sum of three terms to be zero , but since they are all either zero or positive, it is requiring them all to be zero. Could also have been done (perhaps more clearly) with `max( abs(H[1]+H[7] -1), abs(H[2]), abs(H[3]) )`

Comment: I appreciate your help on this.  I accepted your answer because it works but I was wondering if you could clarify a couple things.  When I look at the example on cran, it looks like you can use an eqn function that returns multiple values in a vector.  So the function could return c( abs(H[1]+H[7] -1), abs(H[2]), abs(H[3]) ) and then the optimizer would evaluate each expression individually.  I could not get this to work but I notice that your solution does work so I am wondering if I was just misinterpreting.  Also, I do want to hold the risk associated with k2 constant.

Comment: Notice that I started the parameters out so that they met the equality and bound constraints. I think that is a good idea because the main function might otherwise have difficulty knowing which direction to "move" if they were outside the feasible region.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what "example on CRAN" you might be looking at. Both of the examples on the `?auglag` help page that I see do return values of length-1 for 'heg'-args.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nloptr/nloptr.pdf page 7 under the Powell Problem example

Comment: Ok, I see it, same as help page, named "eqn1". So ... I don't know.